# Assign bound data from code, not xaml

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, user-controls

Im new to WP7 Silverlight, and have a simple problem.

I have a ListBox with a DataTemplate, I can bind and show data with Text="{Binding JobLocation}", that works fine.

I also have a UserControl, which can also bind to JobLocation using Text="{Binding JobLocation}" !

My question is this, I need to do some work on the JobLocation before I display it, so I would like to save it to a variable, like :-

```
Dim jobLocation as string ="{Binding JobLocation}"
jobLocation = // do the work on it
txtJobLocation.Text = jobLocation
```

this would be done in the UserControl code.

Please help, really stuck on this!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to get the bound value from the control, manipulating it and applying the new value back to the control, you should manipulate the values in the underlying object, (and let the binding framework update the control). If you don't want the underlying object to change, you could do the work that you want to do in a ValueConverter and apply it to your binding.

The ValueConverter option is only really appropriate if the work you are doing is trivial and of a presentational nature. Otherwise it is better to set up a separate object to use for your binding, and do the work there. With a separate object you would need to think about a mechanism for updating it when the source data object changes (if appropriate/required).

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out!

The user control inherits the datacontext from it's parent, so simply had to do

```
dim job as Database.Model.Job = DataContext

dim JobLocation as string = job.JobLocation
```

Hope this helps someone else!